# node.js http module http.createServer how does it work?

Tags: node.js, http

so i'm trying to understand how to use node.js module "http" http.createServer()
i wonder if it's possible to see how this function is defined? can i find the content of the definition?  i wasn't able to find it

Comment: Have you at least read the documentation? http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: of course i read the documentation. it doesn't include any code that defines the function

Comment: The approach of checking the source code to understand a function is often overkill. When using external modules, we are expected to read their interfaces and understand the concepts involved. You may however, have a particular issue in your code that led you into thinking if the implementation of that function is either compromised or hiding some other obscure aspect, which I don't think so.

Comment: @E_net4 For what it's worth, I have had at least a handful of occasions where the Node.js documentation was particularly poor, and I've had to dig into the source to figure out what was happening.  This isn't as much of a problem these days as it used to be, and I think the HTTP module is decently documented, but I don't think it's overkill to actually look at how something works to try to fully understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Node.js source code is available on Github](https://github.com/joyent/node).  For the JavaScript side of the API, take a look in the `lib` directory.

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L61

```
exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
};
```

You can find the actual [HTTP server JavaScript in `lib/_http_server.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js).

Comment: Thanks! its pretty helpful

Comment: Where does this code live in Ubuntu? when you install Node.js in Ubuntu, where does it install all its modules? Like `http`, `net`, others